# Почему crash'атся JavaScript'ы?

Tags: javascript

Подключил буквально вчера на свой прожект онлайн-радио.
Всё прекрасно, НО!
При возврате по меню, допустим, на центральную пагу или на какую другую пагу сайта, происходит тотальный crash всех script'ов.
Но стоит нажать в паге F5, всё, естественно, встаёт на свои прежние места.
Как это можно обойти, победить?
Допустим, из [(пример - online radio)](http://krasnoyarsk.front.ru/radio.html)  перейти в "Главная" или "Графика". Особенно совсем crash'ится первая ("Главная").

Может, есть возможность отключать скрипты при уходе с паги?

P.S. Что примечательно, что на локальной версии всё крутиться нормально. И ни чего не crash'ится.

Comment: Советую Вам подчистить все на сайте до нормального состояния, использовать Ajax для загрузки нужных кусков HTML, исправить ошибки(в консоль страшно смотреть) и в первую очередь отнестись с подозрением к _main_min.js. Какой-то скрипт копается в истории и блокирует нормальную загрузку файлов. То, что у Вас сейчас там творится, напоминает утро после выпускного.

Comment: @Alex Krass  
Спасибо за уделённое внимание.  
Приму к сведению и дальнейшему исправлению.
P.S. Более-менее подправил, осталась только подружить данное "детище" с Opera.

Answer (score 2):

Вы пишите:

> Что примечательно, что на локальной версии всё крутиться нормально. И ни чего не crash'ится.

Для интереса, посмотрите пути JS и PHP. Сравните на локале и хостинге соответственно.

Comment: Ну как бы сайт запилен на голом HTML+CSS+JS  
PHP и MySQl нет вовсе, так как хостер не позволяет.  
И на локалке тестится без включения web-сервера, просто, как обычная локальная страничка, лежащая на винте.
Т.е. абсолютные пути сохранены, относительные тоже. И на локалке, и на хостинге.  
@Вячеслав Кириченко, и ещё что примечательно, после нажатия Фэ5 всё же начинает работать нормально.  
Так что пути вряд ли здесь при чём. Фэ5 пути не переписывает ведь.
---
На статике из страниц в страницу, кроме cookie, что-нибудь ещё передаётся?